# Tinymce WYSIWYG Editor blocked in logrocket

Tags: tinymce, content-security-policy, screen-recording, logrocket

Does Tinymce editor have any security functionality built-in that would blocked services like logrocket from seeing the text in the editor, and if so is there a way to disable it? I spoke with logrocket support and they informed me that it's not been blocked by them.